# Find duplicates, update database with minimum value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, database, duplicate

`Sub Update_data()

```
Dim Bk1 As Workbook 
Dim Bk2 As Workbook 
Dim Rng1 As Range 

Workbooks("Book1").Activate 'indicate wb name1 here
Set Bk1 = ActiveWorkbook 
Workbooks("Book2").Activate 'indicate wb name2 here
Set Bk2 = ActiveWorkbook 


Bk1.Activate 
Set Rng1 = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 2)) 

Rng1.Copy 
Cells(1, 26).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 
Cells(1, 26).AutoFilter 
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Rng1.Offset(0, 25), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending 
Cells(1, 26).AutoFilter 

Rng1.Offset(0, 25).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes 
Rng1.Offset(1, 25).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy" 

Dim i As Integer 

For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 26).End(xlUp).Row 
    Dim x As String 
    x = Cells(i, 26).Value 
    Bk2.Activate 
    Dim y As Integer 
    On Error Resume Next 
    y = WorksheetFunction.Match(x, Bk2.Worksheets(1).Columns(1)) 
    Bk2.Worksheets(1).Cells(y, 2) = Bk1.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 27) 

    Bk1.Activate 
Next i 

Rng1.Offset(0, 25).ClearContents`
```

Kindly help me with VBA macro to achieve the below.

I have two workbooks - Workbook 1 and workbook 2

WB 1 is where the data is entered.
WB 2 is the Database. (There are no duplicates in this WB)

From WB1 If there are duplicates in column A then check if corresponding values in Column B is minimum value of the duplicates.

Then copy the corresponding A & B cells in which B has the minimum value along with other data in A & B column and match Column A of WB1 with Column A of WB 2 if match found then paste the minimum value found among the duplicates in Column B of WB1 into column B of WB2 along with the other original data in column A and B in WB1.

I was able to achieve the above with the attached code created by MAX,

but found minor error while testing. 
If the WB 2 (database) is in ascending order then the Macro works well, but if the WB2 (database) is not in order or jumbled up then it leaves some of the cells blank in column B of WB 2.

Also I tried entering data without any duplicates in WB1 (data capture col A) and it returned with incorrect data (date - Col B) in WB 2

I have attached the example image for your review.

[https://www.dropbox.com/s/0vq76uvzs2rav3q/NIHL%20data%20Capturesample.xls?dl=0]

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Dear @teylyn thank you for pointing that out. I have now added the question. please could you help achieve the above results as shown in the image.

Comment: Do you want somebody to write the code for you? If so, you're in the wrong place. This site does not provide free coding services. What is your code so far? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

As @teylyn already explained in the comments, we are not a code writing service. And to add to that, you code is a mess. I'll try to give you some hints and hope to encourage you to rewrite your code yourself.

- `Dim` is used to declare variables. Put all the `Dim` statements at the top.
- Try to understand what your code does, and remove all duplicate/non-functional/repeating code
- Read the Microsoft Technet documentation of the functions you use. For the `Match` function, [it clearly states](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/match.php):

  > "The MATCH function will find the largest value that is less than or
  >   equal to value. You should be sure to sort your array in ascending
  >   order."
- Put some comments above every section of your code (every 3 to 8 lines of code), explaining what it does.
- Don't use `.Activate` to switch between workbooks. As you have defined two `Workbook` objects, you can access the data in the sheet via `WorkbookObject.Range(<etc.>)`. This makes your code *much* faster, and it hides the switching of workbooks for the user who presses the button.